# Python urllib.request.urlopen: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, urllib

I am using Python 3 and trying to connect to `dstk`. I am getting an error with `urllib` package.

I researched a lot on SO and could not find anything similar to this problem.

```
api_url = self.api_base+'/street2coordinates'
api_body = json.dumps(addresses)
#api_url=api_url.encode("utf-8")
#api_body=api_body.encode("utf-8")
print(type(api_url))
response_string = six.moves.urllib.request.urlopen(api_url, api_body).read()
response = json.loads(response_string)
```

If I do not encode the `api_url` and `api_body` I get the below:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1247, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
```

However if I try and encode them to `utf-8` (uncommenting the lines) then I get the below error:

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 514, in open
    req.data = data
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'data'
```

This seems like a circular error for me and I am not able to resolve it. I did try make to solutions from SO regards to change it to `json.load` etc but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Additionally I also added decode, which seemed to error out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding both the url and the request body, but only the body should be encoded.

This ought to work:

```
api_url = self.api_base+'/street2coordinates'
api_body = json.dumps(addresses)
api_body=api_body.encode("utf-8")
response_string = six.moves.urllib.request.urlopen(api_url, api_body).read()
response = json.loads(response_string)
```

`urlopen`'s arguments are passed to another class to create an opener, and this class does not know whether it has been passed a url or a `Request` instance.  So it checks whether the "url" is a string - if the "url" is a string, it creates a `Request`, if not it assumes that "url" is a `Request` instance and tries to set its data attribute, causing the exception that you are seeing.

The code in question is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46f6c566a888fb637913ef71fed28568180eafb4/Lib/urllib/request.py#L507).