# urlopen: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Tags: python, character-encoding, urlencode, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to open a json file from an API with includes characters of the polish alphabet. I have tried to encode the url into utf-8 but still all kind of problems pop up. I include the code I wrote and the error that appears.

```
import urllib.request as request
import json
url='https://api.um.warszawa.pl/api/action/dbtimetable_get?id=myapiID&busstopId=wartość&busstopNr=wartość&line=wartość&apikey=wartość'
url=url.encode('utf-8')
with request.urlopen(url) as response:
    source = response.read()
    data = json.loads(source)
```

Then the error: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout' appears.

Comment: post the full traceback. are you on python 2 or 3?

Comment: Could you also try posting the result of printing the object that it says has no attribute 'timeout' ?

Comment: That's interesting... here somebody seemed to have solved that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916684/cant-open-unicode-url-with-python. But I tried your version and I also have the `timeout` error: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'`. I tried to tweak it with a custom class: `class StringWithTimeout(str):
    def __new__(cls, string, timeout):
        obj = str.__new__(cls, string)
        setattr(obj, 'timeout', timeout)
        return obj`. But then I get `URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: b'https>`

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Yet another potential solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395705/unicode-string-in-urllib-request

Comment: I am using python 3.7.3 @deponovo

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here, probably both stemming from the requirement to access a url with query components that include non-ASCII characters.

- Firstly, passing a `bytes` instance to `urlopen` will lead to unexpected behaviour, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58087071/5320906)
- Secondly, non-ASCII characters in a URL's query parameters are not permitted, so the query parameters must be urlencoded.

So given the invalid url, you need to do something like this:

```py
import json
from urllib import parse
from urllib import request

parts = parse.urlsplit(url)
query_dict = parse.parse_qs(parts.query)
encoded_query = parse.urlencode(query_dict)
fixed_url = parse.urlunsplit((parts.scheme, parts.netloc, parts.path, encoded_query, parts.fragment))
response = request.urlopen(fixed_url)

print(json.load(response))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @snakecharmerb. I tried and it seems that there is an issue with non-string sequence or mapping object. I include the exact error for detail. `# non-empty strings will fail this
    890             if len(query) and not isinstance(query[0], tuple):
--> 891                 raise TypeError
    892             # Zero-length sequences of all types will get here and succeed,
    893             # but that's a minor nit.  Since the original implementation

TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
`

Comment: Sorry, I missed a step in the answer.  It should work now.